# Gallery of this nature

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, preload

I need to make a gallery that is similar to this page, [Gallery](http://design.jchongstudio.com/GO-Business-Cards) but i'm a complete novice with javascript/jquery, sometimes just making a alert script can throw me off lol

Kan anyone point me in the right direction as to what to look for as i'm in completely over my head!?

Answer (score 0):

I think that for something like that you'd benefit a lot by using twitter bootstrap. I has that gallery practically done and with extras.

You don't really need js for that , css 3.0 should suffice.

Comment: While I agree with your statements; jQuery should be used when you're forced to support browsers that don't support CSS3

Comment: He could use modernizr or a bunch of other scripts to make it compatible, but any ways I think you have that in bootstrap (even the jquery it self)